# Powershell - Filter git-for-each-ref omitting certain refname values

Tags: git, powershell

I'm running the following git command in Powershell

`git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/remotes --format='%(refname:short)%09%(committername)'`

How would I filter out (not list) branches where the refname begins with 'origin/Release'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-match` regex comparison operator - like other comparison operators in PowerShell, it'll act as a filter if you pass an array on the left-hand side:

```
$branchesWithCommitter = @(git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/remotes --format='%(refname:short)%09%(committername)')

$branchesWithCommitter -match '^origin/release'
```

The `@(...)` array subexpression operator will block until `git.exe` returns.

If you want to see the lines as they're output from git.exe in near-real time, pipe the output to `Where-Object` and use `-match` on each individual line:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/remotes --format='%(refname:short)%09%(committername)' |Where-Object { $_ -match '^origin/release' }
```

Comment: Actually, I found that I needed ```-notmatch```

Comment: @MB34 feel free to substitute with whatever comparison operator is most appropriate (`-match`, '-notmatch', `-like`, `-notlike` and their case-sensitive versions)